Cascade picklist workitem field in Azure Devops Server 2022
We were trying to achieve cascaded picklist feature to our work item, so that we can use the Work item for our support request from end users where want to achieve  support hierarchy as provided in the image.
Below is the suggestions got from another post, AzureDevops Server 2008- Workitem Cascading filed are not working w
Is there any inbuilt feature with ADO server 2022 to have this dynamic picklist option?
Also the given extensions "Picklist & Multi Pickers Field control " documents are not clear and steps are not given.

Any reference?

Did you also try the extension Dependent Lists? From the image you posted previously, can you explain clearly what are the work item field names and what are the possible values list for each field?

Can you also explain clearly when selecting a value from the list of a field, you want another field will have which values are listed? Show us the detailed logical the Cascade picklist you want. From the the image you posted previously, we cannot understand the full logical.

I have added the image which explains mynscenario. Here looking for a tree structure for work item. For example when users create a workitem for support request, they should get options like cloud, devsecops tools, etc.. According to their each selection , the custom fieldnrelates their previous selection should come. Moreover they will get proper workitem fields relevant to their workiten scope will. Be shown and there they can provide details and raise the wirkitem as support request

I don't think the screenshot can make us fully understand the logical of your demands on the Cascade picklist. If selecting 'Cloud' as value of the first level filed, then what is/are the next fields, and what values do you want the next fields can list for users to select? In addition, what do you mean Access ---> 'Cloud'? Can you descript an example of the process? @Vowneee

Eg: user needs "resource creation" request under cloud with concerned team, From work item, the user can navigatelike first can pick "support request", which will have child field options as"cloud, DevopsToolA, B, etc).. there once the user picked the "cloud" option, he will be getting options as "Access, Resource creation, Type1, 2, etc..) finally once he select the "Resource creation, The fileds related to the Resource creation will be listed and .. user can submit the details... Seems its more a kind of nested template looping.. and not just a picklist option will fulfill the requirement

Yes, the Cascade picklist seems is not able to let a field display/hide based on the selected value from a previous field. It generally just let some items display/hide from the picklist based on the selected value from a previous field. @Vowneee
